# SSL pinning client encryption

Tags: android, ios, ssl, encryption

I want to understand how the security works here.  If I use SSL pinning for my mobile app, I use AFNetwork's AFSecurityPolicy to Pin PublicKey.  When my client connect to the server, I can verify the Server's Certificate because I've pinned it.

Here is the question, am I using the Server's public Key to encrypt traffic to the server. And the Server is using it's private key to send traffic to the client?

Comment: Why does it depend?  I mean, how can the traffic be just encrypted one way on a SSL?

Comment: What do you mean with "just encrypted one way"? SSL always encrypts in both directions (or not at all for the NULL cipher, of course).

Comment: My question is if it does encrypt both ways, which key does each party use to encrypt.  I know the Client would use the Server's Public key, but what does the server use to encrypt to the client?

Answer (score 1):

No, the RSA key is never directly used to encrypt data for TLS. It's used either to encrypt the *shared secret* (for a ciphersuite starting with `RSA_` without downgrade to DH) or it is used to perform signature verification during the authentication phase in ephemeral key agreement (ciphersuites starting with `ECDHE_` or `DHE_`).

The shared secret is used with a PRF for key derivation to establish session keys. The session key for encryption will be used to keep data confidential.

More information in the Wikipedia article on [Key Exchange or Key Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Key_exchange_or_key_agreement)

Comment: Ok, so how does the Server send traffic to the Client if my server hasn't asked to verify a client cert?

Comment: It uses the shared secret to establish session keys.... I'll integrate, but you might just want to read the TLS RFC's.

Comment: So in the end the server and client have successfully shared a secret that cannot be retrieved by an attacker. But the server doesn't know who it is talking to if the client hasn't authenticated itself. You can of course authenticate the client using e.g. HTTP BASIC AUTHENTICATION or HTML forms afterwards.

Comment: Great Wikipedia TLS link! It also looks like TLS 1.3 will be a real shakeup! Apple hasn't updated Common Crypto is years, no AES GCM for example.